# How can I add previous column values to to get new value in Excel?

Tags: excel, xlsxwriter

I am working on graph and in need data in below format. I have data in `COL A`. I need to calculate `COL B` values as in below picture.

What is the formula for obtaining this in excel?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `cumsum` and `shift`:

```
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'COL A': np.arange(11)})

df['COL B'] = df['COL A'].shift(fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    COL A  COL B
0       0      0
1       1      0
2       2      1
3       3      3
4       4      6
5       5     10
6       6     15
7       7     21
8       8     28
9       9     36
10     10     45
```

Comment: i want only excel formula. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple MS technique.
You can use the formula (A3*A2)/2 for COL2

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: MS excel technique*